Traveling from outside the EU to Spain with Carta d’identita?
I'm travelling to EU (Spain) from Argentina next June. I have Italian citizenship and I have the Carta d’identita, Can I use it to enter to Spain?
I have an Argentinian passport, but I used it to enter Europe last year (in February to process my Italian identity card) and then stayed until March of this year, which exceeded the three months I can stay with the Argentine passport, so I cannot use it for entry again.
For additional context: during those months I stayed in Spain and I processed my NIE and European citizen permit, but all that time was with my Argentine passport.

If you're a EU citizen then no one cares how much time you spent in the EU

You can use your passport regardless of the apparent overstay as you are a citizen of an EEA country and as such have no time limits within the Schengen zone, and other EEA countries.
Show your passport and ID card for checking in, and your ID card at immigration, or both at immigration as well.
I have used my Dutch ID card at the Dutch entry point, which was accepted without questions but that immigration check did also get people from flights from countries where that card was all that was needed.
